# How to add a UFunction to an interface's delegate with parameters in UE4 C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am looking use web sockets in Unreal. I am following the tutorial found here: [Web Socket Tutorial](https://www.ue4community.wiki/websocket-client-cpp-5vk7hp9e#connecting-to-the-server)

Most notably I am trying to bind to the events before connection. In the example, they use `.AddLambda` however, I would like to try to use `.AddUFunction`. It seems the function takes in the Object, the function name, and `VarTypes ...types`. I can't seem to figure out what the last parameter is for the delegates that use parameters. (At least I believe that is the problem anyway) The functions themselves have the correct signature and matches the delegates I want to bind to.

Here is what I have so far:

```
void AWebSocketController::CreateWebSocket(FString ServerUrl, FString ServerProtocol)
{
  Socket = FWebSocketsModule::Get().CreateWebSocket(ServerUrl, ServerProtocol);

  // We bind to the events
  Socket->OnConnected().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketConnection"));

  Socket->OnConnectionError().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketConnectionError"));

  Socket->OnClosed().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketClosed"));

  Socket->OnMessage().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketReceiveMessage"));

  Socket->OnMessageSent().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketSentMessage"));

  // And we finally connect to the server. 
  Socket->Connect();

}
```

It gives me the following error messages:

```
error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl AWebSocketController::OnSocketClosed(int,class FString const &,bool)" (?OnSocketClosed@AWebSocketController@@QEAAXHAEBVFString@@_N@Z) already defined in WebSocketController.cpp.obj
error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl AWebSocketController::OnSocketConnection(void)" (?OnSocketConnection@AWebSocketController@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in WebSocketController.cpp.obj
error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl AWebSocketController::OnSocketConnectionError(class FString const &)" (?OnSocketConnectionError@AWebSocketController@@QEAAXAEBVFString@@@Z) already defined in WebSocketController.cpp.obj
error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl AWebSocketController::OnSocketReceiveMessage(class FString const &)" (?OnSocketReceiveMessage@AWebSocketController@@QEAAXAEBVFString@@@Z) already defined in WebSocketController.cpp.obj
error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl AWebSocketController::OnSocketSentMessage(class FString const &)" (?OnSocketSentMessage@AWebSocketController@@QEAAXAEBVFString@@@Z) already defined in WebSocketController.cpp.obj
```

The function definitions:

```
void AWebSocketController::OnSocketConnection()
{
}

void AWebSocketController::OnSocketConnectionError(const FString& ErrorMessage)
{
}

void AWebSocketController::OnSocketClosed(int32 StatusCode, const FString& Reason, bool WasClean)
{
}

void AWebSocketController::OnSocketReceiveMessage(const FString& Message)
{
}

void AWebSocketController::OnSocketSentMessage(const FString& Message)
{
}
```

I have never come across this `.AddUFunction` before and I can't seem to find any examples of how to use it. If anyone can help me out or point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: What class is `this`?

Comment: The `Socket` variable is of type `TSharedPtr<IWebSocket>`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking what class owns the function that the above code is in. Is it `AWebSocketController`? Also, please include your `WebSocketController.h` and `WebSocketController.cpp` files for the sake of including a [mre].

Comment: I don't see how including them will help you but, I will add them. They are just empty definitions.

Comment: Please include your `WebSocketController.h` file for the sake of including a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me!

**SandboxGameInstance.cpp**

```
#include "SandboxGameInstance.h"

#include "WebSocketsModule.h"
#include "IWebSocket.h"       // Socket definition
void USandboxGameInstance::Init()
{
    Super::Init();
    FWebSocketsModule& Module = FModuleManager::LoadModuleChecked<FWebSocketsModule>(TEXT("WebSockets"));

    const FString ServerURL = TEXT("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/"); // Your server URL. You can use ws, wss or wss+insecure.
    const FString ServerProtocol = TEXT("ws");              // The WebServer protocol you want to use.

    TSharedPtr<IWebSocket> Socket = FWebSocketsModule::Get().CreateWebSocket(ServerURL, ServerProtocol);

    // We bind to the events
    Socket->OnConnected().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketConnection"));

    Socket->OnConnectionError().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketConnectionError"));

    Socket->OnClosed().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketClosed"));

    Socket->OnMessage().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketReceiveMessage"));

    Socket->OnMessageSent().AddUFunction(this, FName("OnSocketSentMessage"));

    // And we finally connect to the server. 
    Socket->Connect();
}

void USandboxGameInstance::OnSocketConnection()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("CONNECTED"));
}

void USandboxGameInstance::OnSocketConnectionError(const FString& ErrorMessage)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("ERROR"));
}

void USandboxGameInstance::OnSocketClosed(int32 StatusCode, const FString& Reason, bool WasClean)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("CLOSED"));
}

void USandboxGameInstance::OnSocketReceiveMessage(const FString& Message)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("RECEIVED"));
}

void USandboxGameInstance::OnSocketSentMessage(const FString& Message)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SENT"));
}
```

**SandboxGameInstance.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Engine/GameInstance.h"
#include "SandboxGameInstance.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class SANDBOX_API USandboxGameInstance : public UGameInstance
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    virtual void Init() override;

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnSocketConnection();

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnSocketConnectionError(const FString& ErrorMessage);

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnSocketClosed(int32 StatusCode, const FString& Reason, bool WasClean);

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnSocketReceiveMessage(const FString& Message);

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnSocketSentMessage(const FString& Message);
};
```

Comment: It seems Unreal didn't like me using certain UFUNCTION specifiers. I also switched from AddUFunction to AddUObject.

Comment: A somewhat safer way to do it: '''auto funName = GET_FUNCTION_NAME_CHECKED(USandboxGameInstance, OnSocketConnection); 
someDelegate.AddUFunction(this, funName);'''

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Documentation on [Events](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Events/index.html)

You must declare function signatures that match that of the Event Delegate within your class for which a function pointer will be bound.

[image]

The example image above is from the Engine Source.